# How to share code between multiple projects with react native?

Tags: react-native, bower, bit, yarnpkg, code-sharing

there are some tips like using private npm or using git subdirectory or bower, but not efficient.
another option is bit , but it's not being a straightforward config is the big problem.

is there another tool for code sharing between projects?